# Убрать 0 после запятой в строковом представлении вещественного числа

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, имеется число 12,0.

Как сделать так, что бы в строку записалось число 12 ?

В инете находил какие-то хитроумные самописные функции, неужели нельзя стандартными методами?

Comment: Закрыл как дубликат - т.к. решение не зависит от количества знаков

Comment: Применительно к вашему случаю - это `ToString("0")`

Comment: я бы просто к int - у кастанул.